# Unable to clone laptop display on HDTV

Tags: windows-7, laptop, hdmi, wireless-bridge, cloning

I am trying to clone (not extend) my laptop to a Vizio HDTV.  Facts:
1-Vizio HDTV
2-Eee Asus laptop
3-Wireless HDMI connection via Nyrius Aries Prime capable of 1080p.

I tried Fn/F8 and Microsoft (key)/ P to no avail. HDTV will not show desktop only shows the laptop "theme" but NO icons
Video playing on laptop will not duplicate on HDTV (no cloning).
I also tried settings within the ION n-VIDIA card.  Will not show HDTV as second option.  Also tried within Microsoft display settings and still no solution. Seems like my HDTV is not detected for cloning purpose.  However, I can toggle Fn/F8 and my video will play ONLY on either laptop or HDTV but not on BOTH (as in cloning).  Please help anyone!

Comment: So is it extended? Does Windows Display settings show two screens? Can you move the mouse over to it?

Answer (score 0):

first off how are you connected from your laptop to your tv vga or hdmi? chances are it might be a cable issue not providing the proper signal to your laptop. Also make sure you change your input setting on your tv to tell your tv screen that you are connecting to your laptop.

let me know how that goes.